# Provide / Find all remote routes

Tags: api, laravel

We have a number of separate laravel projects using routes to implement online api's. I am creating a separate laravel 5 project to 'collect' these routes.

As theses routes can change over time, I thought it would be a sensible option to create a route in each separate laravel project which returned a json of available routes in that project. Something like;

```
App\Http\Controllers\RoutesController@routes
```

with method

```
public function routes(Request $request)
{
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $routePaths = [];

    foreach ($routeCollection as $route) {
        $routePaths[] = $route->getPath();
    }

    return response()->json(['routes'=> $routePaths], 200);
}
```

Then the collecting app can simply query this same route for each individual project url. I think this feels like a fairly good solution. However I want to check before I implement this that I am not reinventing the wheel.

Does laravel have a way to 'broadcast' all publicly available routes? - or some way to scan for all available routes from a given url? Or are there better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all routes in the same way that the `artisan route:list` does, you can see the function you can call here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6e31296d6531d0148aadf09c5536b89dda49dc27/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L243